# Need CSS 3 Software

Tags: css

I am developing a web interface and would like to make it beautiful with CSS3. I am not using HTML5. The page will be having styling like **border radius** and **gradient**.

I want a software which validates (and supports) CSS3 styling like `-moz-border-radius`.

Lot of online tools are there, but I want a software that can be **installed** in my PC (to work offline). I am expecting the software to automatically apply `-moz-border` and `webkit border` both (I mean all possible variations and adaptations) for a single control of border radius, all CSS gradient syntax automatically for a gradient control etc.

In short I want a software which gives my complete control over **CSS3**, friendly for a beginner not knowing the syntax. The software may not just use autocomplete since one have to learn the syntax to use, but have controls or options to implement styles over some elements like `<div>`, `<span>` etc. The software may support WYSWYG editing of web page including live page preview (Something like [**Style Master**](http://westciv.com/style_master/)). The software may also notify about multiple browser compatibility.

Help me choose right software.

Comment: HTML and CSS are not compiled languages, and vendor prefixes are **not valid CSS** and you cannot get them to validate at all.

Comment: How is this question still here after five years..? (Belatedly voting to close.)

Comment: Hi blasteralfred, would you consider deleting this question please? It is very much off-topic these days - we can close/delete via the Review Queue, but it would be easier for you to do it.

Comment: @DavidThomas: I am trying to close this again, as a request for off-site resources. Would you mind casting a close vote?

Comment: @halfer: done, and thanks! :)

Comment: Casting another close vote on this.

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure if any editor will automatically apply the webkit declaration when you type in the moz declaration. Having said that, you can try Komodo Edit (it's free and platform independent) which supports all the CSS3 styles and will offer to auto-complete it for you as you start typing the initial few letters of the CSS3 property.

Another thing I d like to add here is, of course this will only solve the border radius issue, you can use the jquery corner plugin wherein you specify the selector and assign the corner function to it like this

```
$(".button").corner();
```

This will apply the moz, webkit etc declarations at run time automatically based on the browser accessing it. There are more ways you can use the corner plugin too.

```
$(".button").corner('5px'); //specify border radius
```

or

```
$(".button").corner('tl tr'); //apply border radius only to top left and top right
```

jQuery corner: http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Komodo Edit: http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit

Comment: +1 @saganbyte for jQuery  info. What I want in the question is a compiler which sets all necessory attributes (and all possible like `moz-border` and `webkit-border` together) via some property set menu. I want all related attributes (thats y i said i want both) since I want cross-browser solution.